# Как сделать задержку между действиями одной функции в js или jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать задержку между действиями одной функции в js или jQuery ? Например добавить один класс, а через какое то время ещё один.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вас интересует анимация, то у jquery есть `.delay()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#foo').click(function() {
    t = $(this);
    t.slideUp().delay(1000).slideDown()
  });
});
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}
#foo.first {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#foo.second {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Если НЕ анимация — то обычный `setTimeout`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#foo').click(function() {
    t = $(this);
    t.addClass('first')
    setTimeout(function() {
      t.addClass('second')
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}
#foo.first {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#foo.second {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

К примеру таким образом. С интервалом в секунду добавляется класс `.red` ко всем `div'ам` с классом `.box`:

```js
var elements = $('.box');
var element  = 0;
var delay = setInterval(function(){
  if (element <= elements.length){
    $(elements[element]).addClass('red');
    element += 1;
  }else{
    clearInterval(delay);
  }
},1000);
```

```css
.red {
    color:red
}
.box {
    display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">1</div> <div class="box">2</div> <div class="box">3</div>
```